# DLTM : Error:Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography

Tags: postgis

How can I store and retrieve position in DLTM projection in PostGIS geography.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Can you please edit your question and explain in detail what you want to do, what you've tried so far and where exactly you ran into problems?

Comment: `geography` is a datatype for geographic (angular) coordinate systems only.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. Instead, use the `geometry` type, which let you set the coordinate system of your choice